# How to create textbox in Microsoft Reporting Service?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have create a report in Microsoft Reporting Service that is presented in a browser. I would like to create button that opens a textbox where the user can fill in text. This text should be saved in column in the underlying database.

Answer (score 2):

That cannot be done, Reporting Services is not for that.

But...... if you really really want to do it, it can be done this way:

- create a report
- in the parameters section have a textbox input like you mention above
- define a dataset that calls a stored procedure*, that stored procedure should take the contents of that textbox as a parameter
- in the stored procedure you can insert that value into a table

*note that it doesn't have to be a stored proc, that just makes it easier. You could just do it straight in the command text of the dataset.

This tip was only for the brave and the demented. Now refer back to the bit where i said *"Reporting Services is not for that"*. This is a very bad practice, **probably worse than using a goto statement**, use it carefully.

Comment: Well I know it's not a handy solution but my thougt was a form called using vb in reporting service. activated by a button. The alternative is a link to a file on the server elsewhere.

I know about the text field but the size is not handy and I cannot see the text